# Single block AES decryption in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cryptography, openssl, aes

I need to play around with some AES snippets.

I've got some cipher text c and a key k. The cipher text has been encrypted using AES-CBC, with the IV prepended. No padding is present, the plain text's length is a multiple of 16.

So I'm doing this:

```
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-CCB")
aes.decrypt
aes.key = k
aes.iv = c[0..15]
aes.update(c[16..63]) + aes.final
```

and it's working just fine.

Now I need to do the CBC mode by hand, so I need "plain" AES decryption of a single block.

I'm trying this:

```
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-ECB")
aes.decrypt
aes.key = k
aes.iv = c[0..15]
aes.update(c[16..31]) + aes.final
```

And it fails with

```
in `final': bad decrypt (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
```

How do I do it?

Comment: How about not setting 'iv'? because there should be no 'iv' on EBC mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are getting the `final` error because it defaults to using padding.

```
decrypter.padding = 0
```

Also to do CBC mode manually with ECB mode, setting the IV will do nothing, you need to XOr the decrypted block with the IV ([or the previous ciphertext block if you end up decrypting more than one block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)).